# Mapper reducer calling in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In Hadoop for 1 mapper , only one mapper object created for one input split which internally calls map methods for each line in input split.  Similarly how many times Reducer gets called ?  one reduce method for each unique key? right

Answer (score 0):

You have control over how many Reducers are used. In your driver you set the number using something like:

`job.setNumReduceTasks(int tasks)`

The default number is `1`.

Using the default `HashPartitioner` keys will be distributed to a reducer based on the hashcode of the key. So a reduce can process multiple keys.

Comment: Thansk MR Nerd ,  Yes that's true.  So, suppose I have set job.setNumReduceTasks(2) and 10 unique keys emited by mapper, Then out of 10 say 7 will allocate to reducer 1 and 3 will allocate to reducer 2. reducer 1 will call reduce function internally 7 times  and reducer 2 will call reduce reduce function 3 times . is that correct ?

Comment: But what decides how many keys go to which reducer. ? for ex 7 key to reducer 1 and 3 keys to reducer 2

Comment: Its the partitioner. The default partitioner just uses the `hashcode` of the key, so its assuming you have an evenly distributed key set, and should generally work well enough. If you start to have reducers that take a lot longer to finish than others, then you might need to look at that in more detail.

Comment: Do you have any idea about Identity Reducer.?  Map only Job or 0 Reducer means no reducer will be called . we can set this via property.  But how to set Identity Reducer. If we have only one reducer but no reduce method implemented , will that be consider as Identity Reducer ?    any real time scenario to use identity Reducer ?

Comment: If you have more questions you should put them in additional questions. I would have a look at some of the hadoop books. Some of you questions above can be quickly answered just by trying it. Please accept my answer if it helped.